# Is there a way to password protect an existing zip file using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a zip file that I created using the JSZip module. Unfortunately, the JSZip module isn't supporting password protection. Is there a way to password-protect an existing zip file?

JSZip node module does support password protection. so is "node-zip". Tried both node modules without much success.

Comment: Implement it on your own when no module exists that satisfy your needs.

Comment: Any pointers or reference is much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself, start with a overview and the specification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)

Answer (score -1):

use the `AdmZip` module, then we set a password for it using the `setPassword()` method, and finally we save the protected zip file using the `writeZip()` method

```
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

// load the existing zip file
const zip = new AdmZip('path/to/existing/zipfile.zip');

// add password protection
zip.setPassword('myPassword');

// save the protected zip file
zip.writeZip('path/to/protected/zipfile.zip');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately zip.setPassword is not function. I am using "adm-zip": "^0.5.10" node module version. If it is working for you, please let me know the version of node module that you are using.

Comment: The same goes with me. zip.setPassword is not a function. Maybe it's available in any other build or just not exists.

Comment: The latest version is 0.5.10. so this answer is wrong